# Être monté comme un taureau

Tags: sens, expressions, étymologie

> être monté comme un taureau

J'ai rencontré cette expression dans une blague:

> Le Diable est perché en haut du clocher de l’église.
>
> Le curé se pose cette question:
>
> -  Mais comment est-il monté ?
>
> Alors, l'une de ses paroissiennes, ayant entendu la question, répond en rougissant et en baissant la tête :
>
> -  Comme un taureau, mon père…

Qu'est-ce que cela veut dire dans ce contexte et d'où vient cette expression ?

Merci d'avance !

Comment: Un des nombreux sens de « monter » est « équiper »,  « pourvoir du nécessaire ». C'est une comparaison entre l'équipement du mâle et celui du taureau.

Comment: Merci pour une bonne explication ! C'est pourquoi j'adore le français. C'est la fête pour les jeux de mots ! :)

Comment: Voir aussi `être bâti comme ...`, ou "légèrement" plus explicite `être membré comme...` :-O  Effectivement, le français est parfois assez... gaulois.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Un des nombreux sens du verbe  « monter », apparu au XII<sup>e</sup> siècle,  est « assembler »,  « mettre en fonctionnement » un meuble, une machine, etc... De là on a eu de nombreux emplois autour de ce sens : « monter un diamant »,  « monter une affaire », pour en arriver à : « équiper », « pourvoir du nécessaire », comme dans « monter son ménage ».

Un mâle qui est « monté comme un taureau », est une expression très familière, sans être grossière, qui veut dire que ce mâle est pourvu d'attributs sexuels d'une taille comparable à ceux d'un taureau.

Pour poursuivre sur le commentaire du PO, le seul jeu de mot est dans le fait que « monter » est employé dans deux sens différents dans la blague, mais il n'y a pas de jeu de mots dans cette expression elle-même qui est une simple comparaison. Je ne crois pas que ce soit particulier au français.
Ce qui est peut-être (je ne m'avance pas trop quand même) plus spécifique au français ce sont des connotations parfois un peu plus grivoises dans les expressions.
L'anglais a l'expression *built like a horse*<sup>1</sup> et l'allemand *ein Mann wie ein Stier*<sup>2</sup> mais ces deux expressions ne sont pas employées uniquement pour parler des attributs masculins et peuvent se dire pour parler d'une carcasse et d'une musculature imposantes.

<sup>1</sup> bâti comme un cheval
<sup>2</sup> un homme qui ressemble à un taureau